# How to remove verbose output for skipped tests?

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-green

Background: 
I have a bunch of tests (20+) which I cannot execute on my working machine, because they require a working CUDA environment. 
So to avoid errors, I've made them conditional through a `unittest.skipIf`.

Abstracting away the details, my test module looks like this:

```
@unittest.skipIf(os.environ.get('TEST_FANCY') != 'yes', "For fancy tests, set TEST_FANCY='yes'")
class FancyTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_a(self):
        self.assertEqual(1+1, 2)

    def test_b(self):
        self.assertEqual(1+2, 3)
```

Now when I run the tests by [`green`](https://github.com/CleanCut/green), every skipped test gets reported in a verbose fashion, polluting the output greatly, e.g.:

```
..ss.

Skipped test.test_fancy.FancyTests.test_a - For fancy tests, set TEST_FANCY='yes'

Skipped test.test_fancy.FancyTests.test_b - For fancy tests, set TEST_FANCY='yes'

Ran 5 tests in 0.355s using 4 processes

OK (passes=3, skips=2)
```

I would like the output to just summarize the results, similar to what the standard unittest runner does by default, i.e.:

```
..ss.

Ran 5 tests in 0.355s using 4 processes

OK (passes=3, skips=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `green` reports the individual skipped tests by default, it allows to suppress these by `-k`. From the [docs](https://github.com/CleanCut/green/blob/master/cli-options.txt):

```
  -k, --no-skip-report  Don't print the report of skipped tests after testing
                        is done. Skips will still show up in the progress
                        report and summary count.
```